# Inside Redux's reducer, can I set a variable in the global (module) scope?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

This is using ReactJS, Redux, and Redux-thunk.

Inside of `reducer/get-data.js`, can I set a

```
let dataFetchingStartTimestamp;
```

in the global scope?  The reason I want to set this in the global scope is so that the function `getData()` is getting data in chunks, so the first time, let's say it gets the first 300 records (assuming 300 records can take 10 seconds), and the second time, another 300 records, and so on, until reaching, say 6000 records. `getData()` would invoke itself after the AJAX succeeded. (the `then` handler of the promise).

When the user changes the UI dropbox, the existing `getData()` loop should stop and restart with new values, and the AJAX that happened earlier should not put data in the Redux state.  So that's why when we have the `dataFetchingStartTimestamp`, we can set it so that when it is the very first time of getting data, the `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` is set to `Date.now()`, and then if the user changes the UI, then it will be another "first time of getting data" and therefore altering `dataFetchingStartTimestamp`.  So inside of this function or in the reducer, if it sees that `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` is not the same as the previous value, then it will not do anything. That means, only operations having the most current `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` will be done.

The way I want to pass this value, is when `getData()` invoke itself after the initial AJAX, pass the `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` to itself, as `dataFetchingContinuationTimestamp`, so this loop will have a value of the `dataFetchingContinuationTimestamp` to compare to the global `dataFetchingStartTimestamp`.

How does the reducer get this value: it will be when the first time, `getData()` dispatches a `GET_DATA_START` together with the payload of `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` for the redux state.  So in the reducer, the statements after the `case` can check whether the current global `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` is the same as in the Redux state.  If they are different, don't alter the state at all.

Can this be done, or maybe there really is a better way to handle it?  We can also use

```
const dataFetchingStartTimestamp = { value: null };
```

if we are only allowed to set a constant, but the `value` will serve as the global value.

Another way is to make `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` a property of `getData` (the function object).

Maybe what is called global here for `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` is not really global, but local to the scope that is packed by webpack, or as a local variable inside the module?

Comment: Reducers meant to be pure functions, so I guess this is not the best idea...

Comment: but can't pure function check the state and act accordingly? For example, even `value: state.value + 1` or `value: state.value % 2 ? "hello" : "world"` is making use of the previous state

Comment: Going through your question at first glance, won't request cancellations work for you?

Comment: request cancelation -- you mean AJAX cancelation? The loop (the function) makes 1 AJAX for 300 records, and when that AJAX is done, calls itself... so I guess if the AJAX can be canceled in time, it should work. But what if the user changing the dropdown box creates an event, and the AJAX finishing also has an event, and BOTH handlers get executed in the same event cycle. I think in the reducer, the case about the previous AJAX returning data is handled if you cancel the AJAX... so I think the only problem is about what if BOTH events are in the same event cycle...

Comment: @Patrickkx by the way, if the reducer sets the AJAX returned data into the state, is that also considered to be pure function? The server can return whatever it wants, so `f(1)` can get back `1` or `3` depending on the server and so it is not a pure function

Comment: @AyushGupta so, when the user changes the dropdown UI, it triggers `getData()` to be called, and seeing it is called as a first time invocation, cancel any existing AJAX call... but what if the AJAX `resolve` and it is the `then` handler, in which case, the AJAX is canceled but the `then` handler is not canceled. Or what if the `then` handler gets executed first, and the function cancels the AJAX... in which case it won't work either. [cont'd]

Comment: But I think maybe the `then` is supposed to be always running after the "major" event handler such as AJAX? (so the `then` is the micro handler that is always right after the main event handler in the same event cycle)... it is complicated but maybe it can work... but using the `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` is more certain

Comment: @Patrickkx and yes, if I use the `timestamp` and also cancel the AJAX, then the reducer won't get called (no data returned), and so there is no "pure function" concern? In this case I don't even need to set the timestamp into the redux state

Comment: @AyushGupta actually, even the reducer may have some issue if we cancel the AJAX. What if the canceling of the AJAX and the AJAX resolve's subsequent `then` handler is invoked in that same cycle? In such case, some "dirty" data goes into the state, but the canceler is thinking it is all clean.  Fortunately if the canceler is dispatching a GET_DATA_START action, it may be better, as it cleans the data in the state, but is it the same event cycle, because if it is, how do you know whether it cleans up before or after then AJAX resolve / then handler?

Comment: But this kind of bug, it can happen 1 / 200 chance or something (if AJAX takes 2 second and each cycle is 11ms. Even harder if the AJAX takes 5 seconds), which makes it hard to appear, and hard to debug. I have worked with other people who just ignore it and saying it rarely happens and if the testing team finds it, just try it 10 times and it doesn't happen and just mark it as unreproducible.

Comment: @nonopolarity Yeah I understand, without additional synchronization mechasisms, you might face race conditions, so using `dataFetchingStartTimestamp` as  a guard can work. However, instead of maintaining state at a global level, can't you maintain it in redux itself and reset it on component unmount, and dispatch it before a request is attempted. Global state with redux _feels_ like antipattern

Comment: @AyushGupta hm actually I looked at the code again, the AJAX calls `resolve`, and trigger the `then` handler, and inside the `then` handler, it then dispatch the `GET_DATA_DONE` so that the reducer will get called with the fetched data. So over there, if I simply don't call itself, and don't do that dispatch, no reducer will ever be called at all. So it should all work out fine. In situations like this, it actually looks like doing it the imperative way (the old jQuery way) makes it simpler

Comment: @nonopolarity But I don't think that the decision of whether or not to update the application state should be AJAX layer. The reducers should be responsible for the decision whether or not to  change the state IMO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218223/discussion-between-nonopolarity-and-ayush-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the problem correctly, user input causes asynchronous actions to dispatch so if user would type in a search input the character `a` and then `b` then 2 searches would be triggered: `a` and `ab`. What if they resolve in a different order than the user provided the input; `ab` search resolves after 1 second and sets state. The `a` search resolves after 1 second and overwrites the result of `ab`. Your UI is now out of sync and is showing `ab` in the search text but search results for `a` (see hidden example below)

```js
const later = (value) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(
      () => resolve(value),
      value.length === 1 ? 2000 : 1000
    )
  );
const asyncFunction = (setter, value) => {
  console.log('starting async with value:', value);
  later(value).then((value) => {
    console.log('resolved with value:', value);
    setter(value);
  });
};
const App = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState('');
  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    asyncFunction(setResult, value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={onChange} />
      <h4>Result:{result}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Below is how you can solve this:

```js
const later = (value) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(
      () => resolve(value),
      value.length === 1 ? 2000 : 1000
    )
  );
const REPLACED = { message: 'REPLACED' };
const resolveLast = (fn) => {
  const check = {};
  return (...args) => {
    const current = {};
    check.current = current;
    //You could make check.current Data.now() but
    //  object reference is guaranteed to be unique
    return Promise.resolve(fn(...args)).then((resolve) =>
      check.current === current
        ? resolve
        : Promise.reject(REPLACED)
    );
  };
};
const lastLater = resolveLast(later);

const asyncFunction = (setter, value) => {
  console.log('starting async with value:', value);
  lastLater(value)
    .then((value) => {
      console.log('resolved with value:', value);
      setter(value);
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      err === REPLACED
        ? console.log(
            `request for ${value} replaced with newer request`
          )
        : Promise.reject(err)
    );
};
const App = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = React.useState('');
  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    asyncFunction(setResult, value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={onChange} />
      <h4>Result:{result}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```